# Laravel displaying html div without images

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5

When we are using text editor we can add different html tags. Like image, videos. 
But i just want to show text fields. If i try `{{$loop->content}}` it prints

```
<p><strong>EXAMPLE</strong></p><img src='/..'>
```

But when try to `{!! $loop->content !!}` it prints "**EXAMPLE**" + "image"
I just want to print "**EXAMPLE**". Not an image. How can i make this? 
Is there a way to do this in laravel shortcodes, php functions or css things? I searched the docs but not found. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any control over the `$loop->content` contents?
is it html? If you just want to remove the image, than you should remove it before it gets to the view, stripping html tags would remove all tags, including `strong`

You should provide more info on `$loop->content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{strip_tags($loop->content)}}
```

Hope this will help you to remove the img tag